# Access Cocoapods resource_bundles

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm struggling with localized resources defined in my own pod.

This pod uses Base Internationalization with the following files:

```
Base.lproj
|- Localizable.strings
|- MyViewController.xib

fr.lproj
|- Localizable.strings
|- MyViewController.strings
```

This is how they are defined in my `podspec`:

```
spec.resources = "MySDK/*.lproj/*"
```

In my app's `Podfile`, my pod is defined as a local dependency:

```
pod 'MySDK', :path => '../MySDK'
```

After I run `pod install`, I can see the **exact same** `lproj` folders in `Development Pods/MySDK/Resources/MySDK`.

`MyViewController.xib` is perfectly loaded and localized, I can change the language on my phone and the text changes accordingly.

In order to use the localized strings, I have defined a function in my SDK pod:

```
public func NSLocalizedIntentString(key: String) -> String {
    let sdkBundle = NSBundle(forClass: MySDKClass.self)
    return NSLocalizedString(key, tableName: nil, bundle: sdkBundle, value: key, comment: "")
}
```

It works, except that **it only uses the string defined in `Base.lproj`, whatever the selected language on the phone or simulator**.

I changed my `podspec` for:

```
spec.resource_bundles = {
    "MySDK" => ["MySDK/*.lproj"]
}
```

in order to load the bundle from the code, but now nothing works, the XIB can't get loaded. It's strange because in `Development Pods` I can still see the exact same structure as before, but with blue folder icons instead of yellow.

Here is how I load my XIB from my SDK, not from my app:

`MyViewController.swift`

```
public init(...) {
    ...
    super.init(nibName: "MyViewController", bundle: NSBundle(forClass: MyViewController.self))
}
```

I changed it for:

```
public init(...) {
    ...
    super.init(nibName: "MyViewController", bundle: NSBundle(path: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("MySDK", ofType: "bundle")!))
}
```

but it can't find the bundle.

I've read tons of documentation and forums since this morning without success, so any help would be more than welcome! :)

Comment: You're presumably using frameworks?

Comment: Yes indeed, I have `use_frameworks!` in my `Podfile`.

Answer (score 4):

I finally figured it out.

1. I switched back to `spec.resources` instead of `spec.resource_bundles` in my `podspec` because I couldn't access the generated bundle.
2. Then I had to turn off localization for the XIB, because I realized that the resources in the lang subdirectories are not compiled. Thus, the XIB are now outside the `lproj` directories.

   My new `podspec`:

   ```
   spec.resources = "MySDK/*.lproj", "MySDK/*.xib"
   ```

   Note that I copy the `lproj` directories themselves (`*.lproj`), not the *content* of the `lproj` directories (`*.lproj/*`), because the `Localizable.strings` would override each other. I need to keep them in their lang subdirectories.
3. Finally, I access the SDK bundle with:

   ```
   NSBundle(forClass: MySDKClass.self)
   ```

I'm still not 100% satisfied because I didn't manage to use the new `spec.resource_bundles` property. But anyway, it works.

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with this on and off for a week.

The most elucidating thing I found so far was this: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/4635

The above pull requests states in order to use resource_bundle you have to use the `RESOURCEDIR/**/*` glob pattern. It doesn't seem to matter what `RESOURCEDIR` is. I had been trying all sorts of things, but that `**/*` glob results in Xcode recognizing the localization directories.

You can try to reproduce my results

1. Use `pod lib create` to create a new project
2. Select Yes to include a demo application when prompted
3. Use Finder to go to the Assets folder and add a `Base.lproj` directory
4. In the podspec file, uncomment the `s.resource_bundles` section and change `*.png` to `**/*`
5. Use the terminal to run `pod install`

Now in Xcode you should see the Assets folder with a Base.lproj folder.

1. Add an xib or storyboard to the Base.lproj.
2. Add a label that you want to translate.
3. Add a class to support the xib or storyboard
4. Run `pod install` again to bring in the new file
5. Select the Pods project in the project navigator
6. Run Editor > Export for Localization.

That should produce an XLIFF file you can use to make translations, then use the Editor > Import Localizations to bring in the translations.

**Note** You might have to run Build > Clean after importing your translations.

**Note** It seems the project that is including the pod also has to support localization.